# IE9 not initially recognising the height of a pseudo element with a SVG background image

Tags: css, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have a weird problem that is best explained by just looking at the live example in IE9:

http://brandonintermediate.spikeatschool.co.nz

Notice the 'uber' or hover state has a white triangle on the right hand side of the indexbar button that created a ribbon end effect.

In IE9, the SVG is initially shown to scale, but then once you hover over that bigger button in the list, it somehow realises that it needs to stretch the SVG to fit the area, and then also displays the ribbon end properly on normal sized buttons too. I'm not sure what's going on here and have already tried several things to fix it. I'm hoping it's not too hard to fix. Here's the CSS that creates the effect along with the SVG code:

```
nav#main ul li a:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #333333;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #000000));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#333333, #000000);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#333333, #000000);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#333333, #000000);
  background: linear-gradient(#333333, #000000);
  *zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FF333333', endColorstr='#FF000000');
  margin: 0 -5px 0 -20px;
  padding: 6px 14px 6px 29px;
  position: relative;
}

nav#main ul li a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("triangle.svg");
  background-size: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="m100,0 l0,100 l-100,-50 l100,-50z" stroke-width="0" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this:

```
&:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('triangle.svg');
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="m100,0 l0,100 l-100,-50 l100,-50z" stroke-width="0" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
</svg>
```

The key difference was the background-size property. This also fixed it in Firefox.